# Jquery Enable/Disable Form With Checkbox

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I swear I looked here and googled every different way I could ask the question but none of the answers solve my simple problem.

I have a billing form and a shipping form on the same page.

When you check the checkbox in the billing form, it disables the shipping form and enables it once the checkbox is unchecked.

I got this to work but once I uncheck it and check the box the second time, the disable property (.prop) is not added although the addClass('disabled') is.

Thanks for your help with this.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col_4">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Billing Information</legend>

        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sameasbilling">Ship to Same As Billing Address</input>
        </p>


        <label for="bfname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="bfname" class="required" name="fname" minlength="2" />
        <label for="blname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="blname" class="required" name="lname" minlength="2" />
        <label for="baddress">Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="baddress" class="required" name="address" minlength="2" />
        <label for="baddress2">Suite/Apt #</label>
        <input type="text" id="baddress2" name="address2" />
        <label for="bcity">City</label>
        <input type="text" id="bcity" name="city" />
        <label for="bstate">State</label>
        <input type="text" id="bstate" name="state" minlength="2" />
        <label for="bzip">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" id="bzip" class="required" name="zip" minlength="5" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="col_4" id="shipping">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" class="required" name="fname" minlength="2" />
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" class="required " name="lname" minlength="2" />
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="address" class="required" name="address" minlength="2" />
        <label for="address2">Suite/Apt #</label>
        <input type="text" id="address2" name="address2" />
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
        <label for="state">State</label>
        <input type="text" id="state" name="state" minlength="2" />
        <label for="zip">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" class="required" name="zip" minlength="5" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <button class="pop orange">Send the order!</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sameasbilling').change(function () {
        if ($('#sameasbilling').is(':checked')) {
            $('#shipping :input').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
            console.log('checked');
        } else {
            $('#shipping :input').removeClass('disabled').removeProp('disabled');
            console.log('unchecked');
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean @mareckmareck. prop adds the disabled property to each input, not the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `prop('disabled',false);`

try this is following working code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sameasbilling').click(function () {
        if ($('#sameasbilling').is(':checked')) {
            $('#shipping input').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
            console.log('checked');
        } else {
            $('#shipping input').removeClass('disabled').prop('disabled', false);
            console.log('unchecked');
        }
    });
})
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQzzn/3/)</kbd>

Comment: @mareckmareck your fiddle is same as mine.

Comment: Thanks @Manwal I tried adding false but I was using removeProp...I see that was my problem. No need to removeProp, just set it to false. Awesome, works perfectly thanks again.